# Навигация по тегам документа html

Tags: phpstorm

Как получить навигацию по тегам html-файла, как на скрине http://joxi.ru/krD8vO6hE9aX0r.jpg ?
Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно включить HTML breadcrumbs: `Settings | Editor | General | Breadcrumbs`, `Show breadcrumbs`. И поставить галку напротив HTML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат будет примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лена, благодарю!